# How can I calculate and create positions of triangle shape?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void FormationTriangle()
{
    newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
    for (int x = 0; x < squadMembers.Count; x++)
    {
        for (int y = x; y < 2 * (squadMembers.Count - x) - 1; y++)
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y);
            newpositions.Add(position);
        }
    }

    move = true;
    formation = Formation.Square;
}
```

The loops are wrong. It put the squadMembers in one line one above the other.
Not even close to a triangle shape.
I want the squadMembers to stand in a triangle shape.

This is the moving part: But the problem is with the loops calculating the triangle shape positions. Other formations I did are working fine.

```
private void MoveToNextFormation()
{
    if (randomSpeed == false)
    {
        if (step.Length > 0)
            step[0] = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
    {
        squadMembers[i].transform.LookAt(newpositions[i]);
        if (randomSpeed == true)
        {
            squadMembers[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            squadMembers[i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[0]);
        }
        if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i]) < 
            threshold)
        {
            if (squareFormation == true)
            {
                Vector3 degrees = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(degrees);
                squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternion, 
                    rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternions[i], 
                    rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because you have more `newpositions` than there are `squadMembers`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## This answer will produce a triangle arranged like this:

> ```
>     x
>    x x
>   x x x
>  x x x x
> x x x x x
> ```

### Or, if there aren't enough to fill a full triangle:

> ```
>     x
>    x x
>   x x x
>  x x x x
> x   x   x
> ```

---

Since you aren't guaranteed a perfectly triangular number of units, you should overestimate how big your triangle is, keep count of how many units you have placed, and then quit placing them when you reach your limit.

First, [find the height of the smallest triangular number greater than your number of units, and that triangular number itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513699/find-row-of-pyramid-based-on-index):

```
int height = Mathf.CeilToInt( (Mathf.Sqrt(8*squadMembers.Count+1f)-1f)/2 ) 
int slots = (int)(height * (height+1f)/2f)
```

Then, find the position of the first unit. We need to know [how many rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513699/find-row-of-pyramid-based-on-index) of slots we have and how wide the bottom row of slots is:

```
float verticalModifier = 0.8f;  // 0.8f to decrease vertical space
float horizontalModifier = 1.25f; // 1.25f to increase horizontal space

float width = 0.5f * (height-1f);
Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(width* horizontalModifier, 0f, (float)(height-1f) * verticalModifier);
```

Then, add until you've added enough

```
int finalRowCount = height - slots + squadMembers.Count;
for (int rowNum = 0 ; rowNum < height && newpositions.Count < squadMembers.Count; rowNum++) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rowNum+1 && newpositions.Count < squadMembers.Count ; i++ ) {
        float xOffset = 0f;

        if (rowNum+1 == height) {
            // If we're in the last row, stretch it ...
            if (finalRowCount !=1) {
                // Unless there's only one item in the last row. 
                // If that's the case, leave it centered.

                xOffset = Mathf.Lerp(
                        rowNum/2f,
                        -rowNum/2f,
                        i/(finalRowCount-1f)
                        ) * horizontalModifier;
            }
        }
        else {
            xOffset = (i-rowNum /2f) * horizontalModifier; 
        }

        float yOffset = (float)rowNum * verticalModifier; 

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(
                startPos.x + xOffset, 0f, startPos.y - yOffset);
        newpositions.Add(position);

    }
}
```

Comment: The triangle is not accurate. Look at this screenshot in the link please. The most right row the second object capsule from the bottom is too outside the right row is not straight like the left row. https://imgur.com/a/9zOP3aj

Comment: That's intentional. That's not a triangular number of units so it makes another row and fills it up as much as it can.

Comment: I'm a few hours I'll edit this to make the bottom row spread out all the way. Can't do it on my phone.

Comment: It's working the problem is with my other script that I did for manage the squads I'm using sliders for the amount of squads and members per squad. And not each number of members will make a accurate triangle and it also depending on how many squads I'm creating. I can add the script of it to see what logic can be make for it ?  The idea is to control the number of squads and members in each squad and then make formations from the squads and members.  For now I have 3 formations: Square,Circle,Triangle. I wonder what the logic should be behind it.

Comment: Maybe I should make a new question for that with both scripts the one that manbage the squads and the one that manage the formations ?

Comment: Maybe you can have your slider choose the height of the triangle, and display the corresponding triangle number. `N = (h+1)*h/2`. Anyway, I edited my answer and now the last line spreads out. If there's only one in the back row, it goes to the center of the row.

Answer (score 6):

Let's see what the list of positions contains for a simple value, `n = 3`

First, loop x from 0 to 2 (`3 - 1`)
Then for each x, loop from x to 4-x (`3*2 - x - 1 - 1`)
*Remembering that `a<b` is the same as `a<=b-1`*

That gives us...

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,2
```

Which is a lot of positions. Certainly more than 3 units can occupy! At least it is a triangle:

```
X\Y 0  1  2  3  4  
0   #  #  #  #  #  
1      #  #  #  
2         #
```

The main problem is that you're generating *way* more positions than needed and expecting to fill it somehow.

You need to calculate your width and height based on the area formula for a triangle: `A = (b*h)/2` and you may even want `b=h`, where `A = number of units`.

So, something like this:

```
int b = Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Sqrt(squadMembers.Count));
    for (int x = 0; x < b; x++)
    {
        //the divide by 2 is accounted for with this 2*
        for (int y = x; y < 2 * (b - x) - 1; y++)
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y);
            newpositions.Add(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the squadMembers there are 20 members but after the loops newpositions contain only 18 positions.

Comment: And another thing the triangle shape result is like this: https://imgur.com/a/3u7zooo but it seems like they are standing and I want them to be horizontal shape something like this: https://imgur.com/a/91D1p7M and it should be made by all members and horizontal not vertical.

Comment: I don't know about the loops, but if you change it to `Vector3 position = new Vector3(x,0f,y);` that will arrange them in the desired orientation.

Comment: @Ruzihm This is working for the horizontal orientation but the triangle shape is filled and I want it to be only outline. (Maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: @DubiDuboni I don't understand. What do you mean you only want the outline? And what do you mean, it works for the horizontal orientation?

Comment: @Draco18s Outline I mean making the 3 triangle lines without filling it. When you position the objects make the 3 lines of the rectangle without put objects inside. Like empty triangle.

Comment: Your question does not ask for only an outline. Your original code does not attempt to produce only an outline. Editing your question to ask for that would invalidate answers (and cause your question to be rolled back). As for units being placed vertically instead of horizontally, that's due to Vector3 vs. Vector2 and is easily changed by using `(x,n,y)` instead of `(x,y)` (where `n` is some value, hard coded or otherwise).